# My Gravatar doesn't show up on my 'Edit CV' page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-picture

My Gravatar is associated with the email address that I am also using with OpenID as a login. Also, my profile has the same email address listed. Despite that, my Gravatar picture doesn't show up on my CV. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CV doesn't have the 'Display Gravatar' checkbox checked:

[image: Display Gravatar]

Comment: I can't seem to find this checkbox anywhere.

Comment: When you go to your CV, click 'Edit' on the section containing your name. It's in there.